# JS stack trace : Javascript throws this error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform

I tried to run a js-script on google instance which used to insert data into table on bigquery.I schedule this job on crontab it took 7 hours and then throw following error :

**<--- Last few GCs --->**

[12260:0x563a119041d0] 30493150 ms: Mark-sweep 993.0 (1359.3) -> 992.8 (1351.3) MB, 1205.1 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested

[12260:0x563a119041d0] 30494379 ms: Mark-sweep 992.8 (1351.3) -> 992.8 (1286.3) MB, 1228.1 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested

[12260:0x563a119041d0] 30495597 ms: Mark-sweep 992.8 (1286.3) -> 992.8 (1253.8) MB, 1218.9 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested

**<--- JS stacktrace --->**

Security context: 0x222a51798fe1

```
1: fromString(aka fromString) [buffer.js:314] [bytecode=0x1bfe4a37d209 offset=164](this=0x222a51782241 <undefined>,string=0x30884c6e5451 <Very long string[106448769]>,encoding=0x222a517f01a9 <String[4]: utf8>)

2: from [buffer.js:177] [bytecode=0x1bfe4a37cd11 offset=11](this=0x2e3d93648b31 <JSFunction Buffer (sfi = 0xc8ff13a82d1)>,value=0x30884c6e5451 <Very long string[106448769448769]>,encodin...
```

Comment: Seems like your heap is out of space.

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: You can try `node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./index.js`. This will increase the heap size to 4096 Mb.